# How would I loop through a collection in a separate thread and reflect the current item on the bound ListBox?

Tags: wpf, multithreading, backgroundworker, listcollectionview

I have a ListBox bound to an ObservableCollection.  The items in the collection each signify a different step with a method to perform that step.  What I would like to do is have a BackgroundWorker loop through the collection, run each item's action method, and have the current step be reflected by the ListBox.

My first iteration used no threading and was just to get the step running going.  Now I have created a ListCollectionView, set it to represent the data in the ObservableCollection, and have bound the ListBox's ItemsSource to it instead of the ObservableCollection.  I noticed running through the steps still blocks the UI thread's updates even though I'm explicitly incrementing the CurrentItem.

I want to use the ListCollectionView inside a BackgroundWorker but most examples I'm finding are written assuming you are modifying the contents or sorting of the list.  I don't wish to do this; I simply want to increment the CurrentItem for each iteration.  I'm guessing simply referencing it won't get me very far as it is tied to items on the UI thread and the compiler will complain.  Any thoughts or pointers would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be seeing any complaints from the compiler, but you will be getting exceptions at runtime if you try to update anything that fires an INotifyPropertyChanged PropertyChange from the background thread. There are a few ways around this. You can use Dispatcher.Current.Invoke to just do updates from inside your DoWork method. You can try to rig something through a ProgressChanged handler (runs on the calling thread) and calls to ReportProgress for each completed step. Or you could do the updates in the RunWorkerCompleted handler (also runs on calling thread) and maybe use a series of consecutive BackgroundWorker calls that are triggered from the previous one's completed handler (this can get messy if you don't manage the steps through a generic queue or something similar).

Answer (score 0):

You need to check out [WPF Cross-Thread Collection Binding – Part 4 – The Grand Solution](http://blog.quantumbitdesigns.com/2008/07/22/wpf-cross-thread-collection-binding-part-4-the-grand-solution/) and the source I think is on [QuantumBitDesigns.Core](http://github.com/sergi/evidence/tree/master/QuantumBitDesigns.Core)

This allows you to update a list from another thread and have the changes automaticaly reflected on a bindable observable collection.

[image: Multiple threads updating an Observable Collection]
**Figure: The demo app shows multiple updates to a single ObservableCollection**

I have used this on multiple projects with fantastic results.